# When are types created/deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, static

Let's say I have a static class that's declared globally, such as:

```swift
class SomeStaticClass {
    static var someString = "someValue"
}
```

When is the class created and deallocated (if ever)? My suspicion is it's created lazily and not deallocated, but I'm having trouble finding documentation about when types are allocated/deallocated.

Comment: Yes, in Objective-C you can use `initialize` to see classes come into existence as needed, but there's no way to do that in Swift. It's never deallocated; it is a global.